# Receiving undefined value on node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I need to understand why I'm receiving undefined for commando. I defined it before and command is correct.

I'm trying to get my commands from a directory.

This is a bot

Regards.

```js
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

console.log(`Command read:  ${commandFiles}`);

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('message', msg => {
    let args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/); //Slices off the prefix entirely and then splits it into an array by spaces. / +/ to avoid issues with spaces
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); //Variable by calling args.shift(), which will take the first element in array and return it while also removing it from the original array(so that you dont have the command name string inside the args array).

    console.log(command);

    const commando = client.commands.get(command);

   console.log(commando);
})
```

Comment: What is `client`?  What object/module?  We need to be able to look at the api for that object and see how `commands.get` is supposed to work.

Comment: More code there.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the doc for `new Discord.Collection();` so I can see what the `.get` method is supposed to do.  Do you have a link to that?

Comment: Yup this is the guide. https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-bot-file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your collection is working like a `Map` object, you do this:

```
client.commands.set(command.name, command);
```

but, then you to the `.get()` like this:

```
const commando = client.commands.get(command);
```

I'm thinking that in these two examples that perhaps `command` that you're doing the `.get()` on is not the same as `command.name` that you did the `.set()` on.

Comment: I will try to check that. The thing is how I can load the command in a var after set it up to avoid the undefined . I'm following the example on the guide I shared before and I don't unsterdan what's wrong.